# MySQL Rollup format

Tags: mysql, group-by, rollup

How do I format the "total" row of a `rollup`?

Backgroup
I have a `MySQL` select statement that is using `group by with rollup` it works however, for formatting reasons I need to identify what row is a "detail" and what row is a "total."  Doing this by a simple RowType column that is a 1 or a zero. I figured this would work:

```
select
   if (MyId is null, 1,0) as RowType,
   MyId,        
   sum(Quantity) as Quantity
from MyTable
group by MyId with rollup
```

This does not work.  However, If I create a view of that select statement then select that view and do this it does:

```
Create view MyView as 
select
    MyId,   
    Sum(Quantity) as Quantity     
from MyTable
group by MyId with rollup;

select
    if (MyId is null, 1,0) as RowType,
    MyId,
    Quantity
from MyView;
```

Is there a better way?  I am going to have to do this for a fair amount of queries and maintaining two sets is good way to have errors.

edit: screwed up my second select code and fixed it

Comment: The first query should work. Please explain what "This does not work" means exactly. Sample data, current result and expected result would help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the grouped query into a subquery.

This is needed because grouping doesn't happen after selecting, so the `SELECT` list can't refer to the value created by `WITH ROLLUP` in the same query.

```
select
    if(MyId is null, 1,0) as RowType, MyId, Quantity
FROM (
    SELECT MyId, sum(Quantity) as Quantity
    from MyTable
    group by MyId with rollup
) AS x
```